# JOGL - gluLookAt() - Cube at top left corner

Tags: java, jogl

I have a wire cube: glut.glutWireCube(1);
If I want a cube's front view at the center of the screen I use glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0) and it's ok.
But I need the cube at the left right corner of the screen, when I tried glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 15, 6, -4, 0, 0, 1, 0); the cube went to the top and left but the cube was distorted (inclined lines).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably messed up the coordinates, and to be more specific the center coordinates in the `gluLookAt`

Comment: Set the center coordinates this way was the only way that I could put the cube at the top(setting centery to -4) and left(setting the centerx to 6), pointing the camera down and right. But I didn't understand why the cube was distorted.

Comment: Try reading here, it's because you don't understand how `gluLookAt` works http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/how-does-glulookat-work